# Как работать с сессией в .net core web api?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Я пытался настроить сессию по туториалу. Вот мои файлы. Тут есть дополнительный код в настройках. Может быть причина в нем. Не знаю как исправить ошибку. 
При вызове строки:

```
  HttpContext.Session.SetString("Name", s);
```

Из контроллера:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public void  Get()
    {
        string s = "s";
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Name", s); 
        ...
    }
```

Появляются предупреждение и  ошибка. В предупреждении написано: доступ к истекшей сессии

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession[2] Accessing
>   expired session, Key:6afbd986-e4b0-77ae-db4e-c68ec9270c8c fail:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13] Connection id "0HL7RO9TS0LKI",
>   Request id "0HL7RO9TS0LKI:00000001": An  unhandled exception was
>   thrown by the application. System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   response cannot be cleared, it has  already started sending. at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseExtensions.Clear(HttpResponse
>   response)

Как это можно исправить?
Метод ConfigureServices:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.CookieName = ".MyApp.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()));     

        string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<TestDBContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            foreach (var formatter in config.InputFormatters)
            {
                if (formatter.GetType() == typeof(JsonInputFormatter))
                    ((JsonInputFormatter)formatter).SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                        MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
            }
        });
    }
```

метод Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home2}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            }
        );
    }
```